# remount / move root folder to another partition on centos

Tags: linux, centos, ext4, xfs

We have an EC2/CentOS6 instance with "/" mounted to an EXT4 partition, and now another bigger sized hard disk formatted in XFS attached to the system. Since the former partition for "/" is insufficient in space and no LVM setup,

> what's the steps if we want to move the "/" and all its contents to the
>   new XFS?

Note that it's an staging server so downtime is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

make sure you have a backup, it's a risky mission.

1. Copy you system
   `dd if=/dev/<device_name_fs_is_on> of=/path/to/other/location/filesystem.img bs=1048576 count=20480`
2. Format the new hard drive and create the needed filesystem
3. Copy the file system 
   `dd if=/path/to/other/location/filesystem.img of=/dev/<new_device_name>`
4. Mount the new filesystem
5. Edit fstab.
6. Ask your Data-Center for an `ipkvm` in case something went wrong.
7. reboot

Comment: You then need to grow the "new" root filesystem.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 he doesn't have lvm